# My Payment Methods not Showing for downloadable/virtual product when checkout?

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, payment-methods

My Magento 2.2.6. My Payment methods work properly for product having weight but not Showing My Payment methods with virtual product or downloadable product had no weight, when checkout.

The error message is "No Payment Method available" when checkout[Show If Enable Cash On Delivery & Check / Money order displaying ]. But I configure right and working for product have weight or sample product.

virtual product or downloadable product no need shipping methods my custom payment methods not showing because my payment methods select shipping methods.

For More details issue as [No Payment Method Available Virtual Product](https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2-x/How-to-resolve-quot-No-Payment-Method-available-quot-for/td-p/51180) 
also [our module](https://github.com/sslcommerz/SSLCOMMERZ_MAGENTO_2.0__2.1_EMAIL_V1.2)

Comment: Can you please share console error on checkout?

Comment: Actually  Cash On Delivery &  Check / Money order  displaying for virtual Product, All payment methods show for sample product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last i Got my solution (May be Someone will be help)

return strpos($this->getConfigData('allowed_carrier'), $shippingMethod) !== false;

Change as 
return strpos($this->getConfigData('allowed_carrier'), $shippingMethod) !== true;

Answer (score 0):

Please check the **function isAvailable()** of the class *Sslwireless\Sslcommerz\Model\Sslcommerz.php*

As per the code, your payment method will not available if there is no shipping method. For virtual product or downloadable product only quote, no shipping carrier is available in magento.

I have updated the *isAvailable function* of the class *Sslwireless\Sslcommerz\Model\Sslcommerz.php* to check if quote contains only Virtual products and has not any Shipping Address then the isAvailable function will returns true and your Payment method will be shown on checkout page.

```
public function isAvailable(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null)
{
    if ($quote === null) {
        return false;
    }
    if(!$quote->getIsVirtual() && isset($quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod())){
     return parent::isAvailable($quote) && $this->isCarrierAllowed(
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod()
     );
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```